# Identify a primary diagnosis and a set of secondary diagnosis

Tags: sql, oracle

My requirement:
Group A codes:

```
o   E16.2 
o   E16.1
o   E16.0
o   E11.649
o   E13.641
o   E10.649
o   E15
o   O24.913
```

Patients must have 1 of the above ICD codes AND 1 of the ICD codes below
Group B codes

```
•   E08%
•   E09%
•   E10%
•   E11%
•   E13%
```

My data:

```
ID  DX_CODE VISIT_DT
1   E11     12/20/2015
1   E11.649 1/8/2016
1   E09     2/20/2017
2   E16.2   1/30/2014
2   E13     7/15/2016
3   E11.649 12/2/2018
3   E11.649 7/17/2019
3   E11.649 5/15/2020
4   E16.0   5/20/2021
4   E16.2   4/25/2022
```

I have tried following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.ID
FROM data_table t1
JOIN data_table t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE (t1.DX_CODE IN ('E16.2', 'E16.1', 'E16.0', 'E11.649', 'E13.641', 'E10.649', 'E15', 'O24.913'))
AND (t2.DX_CODE LIKE 'E08%' OR t2.DX_CODE LIKE 'E09%' OR t2.DX_CODE LIKE 'E10%' OR t2.DX_CODE LIKE 'E11%' OR t2.DX_CODE LIKE 'E13%');
```

The issue I'm running into is:
I'm getting rows where a patient has dx code from Group A codes multiple times for multiple visits(e.g. E11.649 twice) and a patient also has two different codes from the must have list for multiple visit(e.g.E11.649, E16.2).

Can someone help?

Comment: Please update your question with the result you want to achieve based on the data you’ve provided. Presumably a Group A code can’t also be a Group B code e.g E11.649?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
with data as (select distinct id, dx_code from data_table)
select p.*, s.*
from data p
join data s on s.id = p.id and s.dx_code <> p.dx_code
where p.dx_code in ('E16.2', 'E16.1', 'E16.0', 'E11.649', 
                    'E13.641', 'E10.649', 'E15', 'O24.913')
  and (s.DX_CODE LIKE 'E08%' OR s.DX_CODE LIKE 'E09%' OR s.DX_CODE LIKE 'E10%' 
    OR s.DX_CODE LIKE 'E11%' OR s.DX_CODE LIKE 'E13%')
```

Result:

```
 ID  DX_CODE  ID  DX_CODE 
 --- -------- --- ------- 
 1   E11.649  1   E11     
 1   E11.649  1   E09     
 2   E16.2    2   E13
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MsX7MZEu).

Comment: Thank you, I just added 'and s.dx_code not in ('E16.2', 'E16.1', 'E16.0', 'E11.649', 
                    'E13.641', 'E10.649', 'E15', 'O24.913')'

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using this query :

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT t1.ID, t1.DX_CODE as DX_CODE_A, t2.DX_CODE as DX_CODE_B
  FROM data_table t1
  JOIN data_table t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
  WHERE (t1.DX_CODE IN ('E16.2', 'E16.1', 'E16.0', 'E11.649', 'E13.641', 'E10.649', 'E15', 'O24.913'))
  AND (t2.DX_CODE LIKE 'E08%' OR t2.DX_CODE LIKE 'E09%' OR t2.DX_CODE LIKE 'E10%' OR t2.DX_CODE LIKE 'E11%' OR t2.DX_CODE LIKE 'E13%')
)
select *
from CTE
where DX_CODE_A <> DX_CODE_B
```